# Issues with foreign constraints -

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, migration

I tried to follow the documentation of laravel and laracasts, however I get an error in my migrations concerning foreign keys.

I have articles about games that are written by authors (users), so I want the user Id for the article.
This is my games table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('games', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('name', 100);
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->string('publisher');
        $table->string('url');
    });
}
```

And this my user table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

If I understand correct I name the column in the games table 'user_id', and it references to the Id of the user, which is called 'id' in the user table?

When migrating however i get the error theres no user_id.

`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'user_id' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table` games`add constraint`games_user_id_foreign `foreign key (`user_id`) references` users `(`id`) on delete cascade)`

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Am I mixing up where I should refer to 'id' in the user table?

Comment: you are migrating table in the wrong order

Comment: you are trying to create a foreign key on a field that doesn't exist ... `games` doesn't have a field named `user_id` .. you have to create the field before you can make it a foreign key

Answer (score 1):

Migrations by default are run with the same order that they are been created, and in your case, the `games` migration is been executed before the `user` migration, and so you when migrating the `games` migration, there is no `user` table, and so

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Will fail.

In order to solve this problem, rename the `user` migration with a date before the one that has the `games` migration

Thanks to @lagbox for having pointed it out:
This line is not creating a new field, but is just adding a constrain

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Instead you should first create the field and then create the constrain:

```
$table->bigInteger('user_id)->...;
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: they never created the `user_id` field on `games` either, which is the actual error at the moment, once fixed, it will be the issue you described here

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually do it is :

- Creating the migrations files (containing all the fields)
- Creating alterations files (adding FK)

Like that, when I run `php artisan migrate` the order of the migrations doesn't block anything.

With your code above you are trying to add a foreign constraint on a field which doesn't exist yet